# Move particular emails to another folder(MS Outlook 2013)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I am using Outlook 2013 (exchange server) I want to move every email or a few particular emails after 20 minutes from inbox to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to achieve what you want with a Filter..... from the ribbon...

(Home tab).... Rules .... Create Rule.

[image: Create Rule dialog]

Then click Advanced Options

[image: Advanced Options]

There's lost of options... date range is fixed, but hopefully you can find something that helps!